# Creating a title with an image

Tags: graphics, titles

I am trying to create a title with an image, using the environment `titlepage`. I would like to have the title on the left and the image on the right, but I do not know exactly how to do it. I know we can flush an image or some text to the right or to the left, but I do not know how to do it. This is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
        \includegraphics{images/img1.pdf} % this should be on the right
        \maketitle % this should be on the left
    \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

This is more or less what I would like to obtain:

[image]

Comment: Either you use a titlepage environment or you delegate the job to \maketitle.. You also can consider udsing the `titling` package.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\begin{document}
  \title{Title}
  \author{Author}
    \begin{titlingpage}
      \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \maketitle % this should be on the left
      \end{minipage}
      \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{images/img1.pdf} % this should be on the right
      \end{minipage}
    \end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```

[image: titling titlingpage]